Touchpad and System Freezing on Two Dell Latitude 7410 Devices After Installing Ubuntu 24 Alongside Windows
I recently purchased two used Dell Latitude 7410 laptops (i5-10310U, 16GB RAM, 256GB SSD, FHD Touchscreen 360-degree) and installed Ubuntu 24 alongside Windows on both.
Here's what happened:
First Device:
After installing LAMP and some work apps, everything seemed fine—until I opened SoundCloud in Google Chrome. The touchpad started freezing repeatedly.
I also noticed the touchpad hung for a brief moment during the Ubuntu installation process itself.
Second Device:
I exchanged the first laptop for another with the same specs. This time, after a similar installation and partition setup (30GB for Windows, 50GB ext4 for root, 16GB swap, and the rest for /home), the touchpad and the entire system started freezing again, but only after playing a YouTube video.
Additional Observations:
The freezing issues aren't limited to Ubuntu—it's also happening in the BIOS. The touchpad hangs, though the touchscreen still works.
When I restart the laptop, it goes directly to Ubuntu, even though "Windows Boot Manager" is listed in the BIOS boot sequence. Windows isn’t shown as an option.
The store confirmed that Windows alone doesn’t have any problems, which leaves me stumped.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues with this model? Any ideas or potential solutions?
Your insights would be greatly appreciated!
